# download file from windows server to linux server without disabling selinux

Tags: selinux

I am developing a site in PHP on Linux Server where I need to download a file from Windows Server to Linux Machine. I can do it with Some Changes in SeLinux or setting some properties(setsebool -P httpd_disable_trans=1) of it. But our client refuses to compromise any security for this functionality So need to find any other work around. Can anyone help?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "download a file from windows server" ? Using a specific protocol ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks the PHP/apache has no access to the samba port or network. See the link http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/SelinuxBooleans.

Try to run 'sealert' to get more information and tips what to fix.

'sealert' is a very smart tool to analyze SELinux denials from log with many tips how to fix it. It is bundled in Fedora and some other distros. Even it requires X server, connect your server with X protocol forwarding works enough.

Answer (score 0):

It all depend on the way you connect to the windows server.

If this is by http, then there is no specific boolean it seems.
If this is done by ftp, there is httpd_can_connect_ftp to allow apache to connect to ftp.
If this is done by a mount over cifs, then you can take a look at httpd_use_cifs.

Getting the exact AVC from /var/log/audit/audit.log would greatly help to find what could have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

SELinux provides a wide range of options to provide access to designated processes/functions/users, etc.  This is referenced from the RedHat Support page for HTTP-servers:

> When SELinux is enabled, the Apache HTTP Server (httpd) runs confined by default. Confined processes run in their own domains, and are separated from other confined processes. If a confined process is compromised by an attacker, depending on SELinux policy configuration, an attacker's access to resources and the possible damage they can do is limited.

Aside from what the other answers mention, namely opening up ports and enabling them to bypass SELinux protocol (which may be an obvious security concern, depending on the context/scope of the directory access), there's also the SELinux context *type*, which you can assign/change to a specific directory to allow the server access to that directory only, and nothing else.

To allow a directory to be written to by the `httpd` service, you need to change its SELinux context label from the default of `httpd_sys_content_t` to `httpd_sys_content_rw_t`.  To make a temporary change to the directory, execute

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t /your_directory/
```

This change will revert to the default after a reboot, or by executing

```
restorecon -R -v /your_directory/
```

To make the changes to the designated directory permanent, do:

```
# semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t "/your_directory(/.*)?"
# restorecon -R -v /your_directory/
```